How to auto-refresh dates on a rolling 2 week period in my Power BI report
I am currently working on a Power BI report connected to a lakehouse in Fabric. Our report tracks a rolling 2-week period using a date filter that references my calendar table. Since our backend dataset refreshes daily, I have to manually update the filter every day to show the latest 2-week period by default. I want to improve efficiency by automating this process so that the date filter updates to the latest rolling 2-week period automatically when our dataset refreshes in the morning. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?
Date Filter
One approach I tried was using bookmarks. I added an extra column to our date table using PySpark code to check whether a date falls within the latest rolling 2-week period available in our fact table.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as spark_max, when, date_sub, lit

def add_rolling_2_weeks_column(spark, transactions_table, calendar_table):
   # Load the tables
   nyce_union_all_trans = spark.table(transactions_table)
   dates_2020_2025 = spark.table(calendar_table)

   # Calculate the max date from the transactions table
   max_date_row = nyce_union_all_trans.agg(spark_max(col("settdate"))).collect()

   # Extract the actual date value from the collected result
   max_date = max_date_row[0][0]

   # Calculate the date 14 days before the max date
   reference_date = date_sub(lit(max_date), 14)

   # Add the new column to the calendar table
   calendar_df = dates_2020_2025.withColumn(
       "Rolling2Weeks",
       when(
           (col("Date") >= reference_date) & (col("Date") <= lit(max_date)),
           "Rolling 2 Weeks"
       ).otherwise("All Time")
   )
   return calendar_df


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateCategorization").getOrCreate()
dates_2020_2025 = add_rolling_2_weeks_column(spark, "nyce_union_all_trans", "dates_2020_2025")

With this setup, I created a hidden filter on the page that selects between “rolling 2 weeks” and “all time.” When “rolling 2 weeks” is selected, it should filter the dates to show only the latest 2 weeks. I then used bookmarks to toggle between a default view showing the rolling 2-week period and an all-time view that allows users to select dates beyond the latest 2 weeks. However, this method doesn’t update the date filter as expected. Instead of automatically showing the latest dates, it remains static, requiring manual updates.
Any help on this would be appreciated!
